# Terraform: provisioner couldn't be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, provisioning, terraform

I have `resource "aws_instance" "webserver"` in my **.tf file** which contains `provisioner "install-apache"`:

```
    provider "aws" {
      access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
      secret_key = "SECRET-KEY"
      region     = "us-east-1"
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
      ami           = "ami-b374d5a5"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"

      provisioner "install-apache" {
        command = "apt-get install nginx"
      }
    }
```

After running `terraform plan` I've got an error:

```
     * aws_instance.webserver: provisioner install-apache couldn't be found
```

According to the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) value must be one of the following:

- chef
- file
- local-exec
- remote-exec

I believe in your case you want the [`remote-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) value

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
  secret_key = "SECRET-KEY"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
  ami           = "ami-b374d5a5"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "apt-get install nginx"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it appears I've skipped the important part in the documentation. Thank you for pointing me to this part! :)